# Change x axis scale in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to change the scale of the x-axis linearly, that is, that the distance between the points was proportional, so I have two points (12.23 and 12.12) that should be glued together and others like 19.35 with 23, 8 that should be well spaced and 23.8 to 24.7 that should be closer, but I was not able to do this correctly.

```
   reset
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key fixed right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox
set style increment default
set datafile missing '-'
set style data linespoints
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror rotate by -45 # autojustify
set xtics  norangelimit 
set xtics ()
set log x
set key center top inside
set title "DC 5,86%" 
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set x2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set yrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set y2range [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set zrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set cbrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback
set rrange [ * : * ] noreverse writeback

plot 'teste2.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title columnheader(2),'teste2.dat' using 3:xtic(1) title columnheader(3)
```

my test2.dat is:

```
    DC      L=1    L>1
42.85   15.98   -
32.5        -   26.09
30.76   23.12   -
24.7        -   31.75
23.8    33.1    -
19.35   42.11   -
14.03   61.72   -
12.23   62.65   -
12.12       -   75.38
10.98   44.58   -
```

I've been trying to do this for some time. Could someone help me with this function?

[image]

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you provided the actual code to produce this graph? The title is different.

Anyway, if you look at your code there is the line `set log x`, so your x-axis is scaled logarithmically. Detlete this line and the scaling should be linear.

Futhermore, actually, you are coding: `using 2:xtic(1)`, this will set the first column as text label.
And the distances between each labels will be 1, not the real x distance.
If you want to have the real x value on the x axis you have to code: `using 1:2`.

A further problem could be that your input data has decimal point where in the output graph I see comma. It could be (not sure) that gnuplot will just take integer values from the input data.

Try the following:

**Code:**

```
### simple plot
reset session

$Data <<EOD
    DC      L=1    L>1
42.85   15.98   -
32.5        -   26.09
30.76   23.12   -
24.7        -   31.75
23.8    33.1    -
19.35   42.11   -
14.03   61.72   -
12.23   62.65   -
12.12       -   75.38
10.98   44.58   -
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 title columnheader(2), \
        '' u 1:3 w lp pt 7 title columnheader(3)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]